# How can I access city name from my list by zip?

Tags: c#, linq

I have one List named Address. Now i want the Address.City name where Address.Zip = 822.
How can I access the name of city from Address list by Select query in list?

Comment: Show your code, and the structure you're accessing and if possible a couple of elements of data for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty trivial LINQ.

```
string city = Address
    .Where(a => a.Zip == 822)
    .Select(a => a.City)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Address obj = list.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Zip == 822);

if (obj != null)
{
  string city = obj.City;
}
```